# React - list.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm experimenting with React and I'm trying to save some data in my localStorage. I'm receiving the error "list.push is not a function" when I try to add some data into my list variable with list.push(data) inside the method onAddOrEdit(). Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TransactionForm from './TransactionForm'

class TransactionList extends Component {

state = {
    list: this.returnList()
}

returnList() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('transactions') == null) {
        localStorage.setItem('transactions', JSON.stringify([]))
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactions'))
    } 
    return localStorage.getItem('transactions');
}

onAddOrEdit = (data) => {        
    var list = this.returnList()
    list.push(data)
    localStorage.setItem('transactions', JSON.stringify(list))
    this.setState({ list })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <TransactionForm
                onAddOrEdit={this.onAddOrEdit}
            />
            <hr />
            <p>List of transactions</p>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TransactionList
```

And the other component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class TransactionForm extends Component {

state = {
    bAccountNo: '',
    iFSC: '',
    bName:'',
    amount:''
}

handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
}

handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onAddOrEdit(this.state)
}

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
            <input name="bAccountNo" placeholder="A/C No." value={this.state.bAccountNo} onChange= 
{this.handleInputChange} /><br></br>
            <input name="iFSC" placeholder="iFSC" value={this.state.iFSC} onChange= 
{this.handleInputChange} /><br></br>
            <input name="bName" placeholder="bName" value={this.state.bName} onChange= 
{this.handleInputChange} /><br></br>
            <input name="amount" placeholder="amount" value={this.state.amount} onChange= 
{this.handleInputChange} /><br></br>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
}

export default TransactionForm;
```

Comment: i think you'll also need to do ```return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactions'))``` in the last line of returnList()

Comment: That did the trick, thanks